# Detect non-existing e-mail address without sending a message

Tags: email

I've read everything I could find on verifying e-mail addresses. The widely encountered solution is [this](http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/), and it doesn't work (for one, actual `nslookup` output differs significantly from what the article shows, so I don't get an actual address to `telnet` to).

But then I thought: I don't need to verify the address. I just want to detect clearly bogus address (such an address that sending a message to it will yield "delivery failed" response). Is it possible to do in principle, and implement using C++ sockets or Java networking API in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which operating system and tools you use, verifying the recipient's domain, and whether it is recorded in the DNS with a meaningful MX (mail exchange), you could use `dig` in place of `nslookup`. For `foo@bar.com`,

```
$ dig bar.com MX
```

Possibilities of detecting bogus eMail adresses are typically limited, though. Availability largely depends on how "generously" the MTA offers this information. Most don't, these days. The SMTP protocol includes some verbs you could then use, such as `VRFY`. On the other hand, spammers could do just that, hence …  (That's one reason why a mail loop is run, in order to detect valid eMails fairly reliably; embedding, as I'm sure you know, a verification string to be sent back, or passed via URL to some web service.

SMTP, being a text protocol, would be used via some "transport layers" underlying higher level APIs like JavaMail. I'd look for programmability of these with the programming language used. Typically, there is some socket library, for sending and retrieving lines of text.